# Primefaces datatable without a h:form

Tags: forms, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces datable in a JSF page. The datatable was not declared in a h:form. Things seemed to work fine until I noticed that its affecting performance of my application. The datatable's value attribute's method was invoked multiple times when I navigate away from the page. When I put the datatable in a h:form tag, things work better. No more multiple invoking of value's method when I navigate away. The value method is declared in a RequestScoped backing bean. What I don't understand here is how using h:form is affecting the datatable?

PS : I know getter method should not have any logic in it. It can be called any number of times.

Comment: With a phaselister debugger, you could see in which phase the difference occurs. And what is 'navigating away'?

Comment: I am not aware of phaselister debugger. I will look for it. I am using p:menubar with p:menuitems in it. The JSF page is one of the menuitem. "Navigating Away" is when I click on another menuitem. I hope I am using the right term.

Comment: PhaseListener sorry... check [here](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html).